# Symfony 5 QueryBuilder Alias ManyToOne

Tags: symfony, alias, query-builder, many-to-one

I am trying to sort data in server side, it works good for all columns but not for the many-to-one relationship.

This is what I tried:

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->where('b.marque LIKE :query')
        ->orWhere('b.editeur LIKE :query')
        ->orWhere('b.logiciel LIKE :query')
        ->setParameter(':query', '%' . $query . '%')

        ->join('b.nature_relation', 'n')->addSelect('n')

        ->setFirstResult($firstResult)
        ->setMaxResults($limit);
        

    foreach ($sort as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'str_Nature') {
            $query->orderBy('n.' . $key, $value);
        } else if ('b.' . $key) {
            $query->orderBy('b.' . $key, $value);
        }
    }
```

What is my mistake ?

Comment: could you please fix your code, because that `||` seems very very very wrong (and the `**` that come after). you also probably want `addSelect` instead of `select`.

Comment: thanks with addSelect its better ,

but the sort for the manyToOne doesn't work

Comment: `if('b.' . $key)` is ALWAYS TRUE. you need a check like `if($key == 'naturerelationfieldname') { ... }`

Comment: better like that ?

Comment: I doubt that `n.nature_relation` even exists.